# how to deal with the problem of sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError？

Tags: python, pandas

```
 i connect 2 database, and then use pandas to make the operation which is like the EXCEPT of SQL, but it seems there is some mistake of decode

 db_new = create_engine(path, encoding='utf-8')
 db_old = create_engine(path, encoding='utf-8')
```

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'event' with text '16787661:�\�89tuc'
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

what i want to say is that the coding of these two databases id utf-8
Though it exist some gibberish , how to execute the code without the problem of decode the column?